# Get Windows user name in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security

I have a Spring-MVC web-app running on Tomcat 7 on a Solaris box.  The web-app is entirely inhouse, on an intranet.  All users who hit the app are running Windows.  Is it possible to obtain their Windows user name when they hit the controller?  I had this working perfectly with Waffle, but that solution doesn't work on Solaris.

Comment: Turns out I had to implement a custom login module.  http://wiki.wsmoak.net/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?TomcatKerberosConfigOnly

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [JCFIS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) library. It [supports](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/ntlmhttpauth.html) NTLM protocol which can pass the credentials from the OS to your webapp. Unfortunately, it works only in IE.